# Application Startup in C#

Tags: c#

We have a little C# startup appplication that users launch to run the latest version of our main C# WinForms application from a network share.  It's kind of a simplified ClickOnce arrangement (our IT folks won't allow us to use ClickOnce).

The startup application exits after calling Process.Start("MainApplication.exe"), but the main application can take several seconds to display, leaving the user with a blank screen.

Is there a way that the starup application can poll the OS to find out if the main aplication is running before it exits?  Or some other way to handle this?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Process.WaitForInputIdle()` to wait until your application enteres the Idle state.

```
Process appProcess = Process.Start("MainApplication.exe");
appProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
```

**From MSDN:**

> ...you have just started a process and
>   want to use its main window handle,
>   consider using the WaitForInputIdle
>   method to allow the process to finish
>   starting, ensuring that the main
>   window handle has been created

Remarks Section from [Process.MainWindowHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx) property.

Comment: +1 I would also have the starter app provide the splash screen during WaitForInputIdle....

Answer (score 7):

You can call [Process.GetProcessByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) to see if the new process has been created.  The other option would be to have your main application kill the startup application once it has finished loading.

Comment: In addition to using this method I would suggest adding a splash or loading screen so the user doesn't have a perception of the application hanging.

Comment: The problem with using GetProcessByName is that the process for his Main application could be started (he'd get a process name) but the GUI may not be drawn on screen yet.

Answer (score 5):

Use Davids' suggestion or alternatively you can put a [splash screen](http://www.codersource.net/csharp_splash_screen.aspx) in your main application. It will be just a simple Form with an image running on a separate worker thread. Put this as the first item invoked on start up. Your app can continue initializing on the main thread & after some seconds  or just before your Main app finishes initialization kill the worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this easily is to use a global event to signal the startup application that the main app has reached a predetermined state.  To do this create a named event handle in the startup application and wait for it to be signaled:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string globalName = "MyProgramName";//something unique

    bool isNew = false;

    ManualResetEvent mreExited = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    EventWaitHandle mreStarted = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, globalName, out isNew);

    try
    {
        if (!isNew)//already running, just exit?
            return;

        //start and monitor for exit
        Process pstarted = Process.Start("...");
        pstarted.Exited += delegate(object o, EventArgs e) { mreExited.Set(); };
        pstarted.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        int index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(new WaitHandle[] { mreExited, mreStarted });

        if (index == 0)//mreExited signaled
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed to start application.");
    }
    finally
    {
        mreExited.Close();
        mreStarted.Close();
    }
}
```

Then in the main program you signal the event once your ready for the startup application to quit:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string globalName = "MyProgramName";//same unique name

    bool isNew = false;
    EventWaitHandle mreStarted = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, globalName, out isNew);
    try
    {
        if (!isNew)
            mreStarted.Set();

        Application.Run(new Form());
    }
    finally
    {
        mreStarted.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think David's second option is the way to go here.  The process may be running with no visible UI yet.  So, once the main form is displayed in the second app, kill the first process.  You could even, conceivably, pass the process id of the original process in via StartInfo when you start the new process.

Answer (score 0):

There are [many trade-offs](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/article.php/c4651) involved in this, but you may be able to make start-up time fast enough to make this issue moot by using [NGEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to put Splash Screen in your application it gives you a good feel rather than if you dont want to use Splash screen then kill the process when loading is finished. Or you can use **Process.GetProcessByName()**

For Splash Screen just make a Window Screen and in startup class just inherit the class from **Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase** that gives you a method **OnCreateSplashScreen()** Override this method like this :-

```
protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
{
    base.OnCreateSplashScreen();
    //yourSplashScreen is the screen you made as a window form either it would be a image or form
    SplashScreen = yourSplashScreen();
}
```

---

Thanks ...Saurabh Singh Happy To Code

---